# Java : Impossible to parse "23/10/1973" with "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" format

Tags: java, android, exception, date-format

I'm trying to parse many string dates to Date(s), some with time part, others without, with the "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" format.

```
public static Date StringToDate (String format, String theDate) {

  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

  Date retDate = null;
  try {
   df.setLenient(true);
   retDate = df.parse(theDate);
  } 
  catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return (retDate);
 }
```

(here, format is always "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").

But this causes an exception, even with setLenient forced at true. Do you know how I may convert to Date a lot of strings formatted like "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", but with someones without time, some others without secondes, and still other one with everything ?

Comment: How about using different format strings depending on the length of the date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that some strings have a time and some don't, and there are no other cases, I'd just check the length of the string.  However, if you have many different formats available, I'd try each one in some order that makes sense, until you get a valid date.

Comment: Wow... ok... but I thought that "lenient" allowed to forget (or not) the time when you pass a shorter string than expected. That don't seem to be the case. So... what is the purpose of "lenient" ?

Comment: @user499417: lenient (which is on by default) parses dates like 2010/13/01 as 2011/01/01 because it is lenient about the number of days in a month and months in the year. The `DateFormt`'s `lenient` property corresponds directly to the `Calendar`'s lenient property. Sadly Java's Date, Calendar, and DateFormat classes leave a lot to be desired, which is why some people use Joda.

Answer (score 0):

I always have two parse strings, and I parse twice; once with date/time and once with date only.